# .NETCore Detail list with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a list of items which I want user to see the detail in another page by clicking below link:

```
<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-action-user" asp-area="" asp-controller="DuctWorks" asp-action="ForceItem" class="itemClick text-muted">@dw.Item</a></td>
```

This link calls an ajax as below to read columns of the table and pass them to controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Pass item information to controller
        $(".itemClick").on('click', function () {
            var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
            var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html();
            var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html();
            var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").html();
            var col4 = currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").html().substring(114);
            col4 = col4.replace('</a>', '');
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                //async:true,
                url: "/DuctWorks/ForceItem",
                data: {
                        jInv: col1,
                        jName: col2,
                        jDwg: col3,
                        iName: col4
                },
                success: function (data) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller then receives the parameters and is to pass them to relevant view:

```
public IActionResult ForceItem(string jInv, string jName, string jDwg, string iName)
    {
        Change_sts changests = new Change_sts()
        {
            job_inv = jInv,
            job_name = jName,
            job_dwg = jDwg,
            item_name = iName
        };
        ViewBag.jInv = changests.job_inv;
        ViewBag.jName = changests.job_name;
        ViewBag.jDwg = changests.job_dwg;
        ViewBag.item = changests.item_name;
        return View();
    }
```

I have tried this link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud) but it only uses one parameter as id.

My code does not work as apparently it is called twice and causes the data to be lost. Is there a reference or a solution which I learn more about the issue?

Comment: You making an ajax call - ajax calls never redirect. If you want to go to another page, use a normal link. And you not even cancelling the default redirect of your submit, so you making 2 calls to it - one using ajax which you do not do anything with, and one normal redirect but don't pass any values to it.

Comment: And you `ForceItem()` code method makes no sense. What is the point of creating an object, and then assigning all its values to `ViewBag` and then throw the object away - use `return View(changests);` to strongly bind to your model and get rid `ViewBag`

Comment: Is that alright to pass data to <a> value and then send to controller? How should I pass multi parameters to controller then?

Comment: By using `asp-route-jInv="..." asp-route-jName="..."` etc (but you should only be passing the ID of the object and getting it again in the controller method anyway.

Comment: Is there any way to pass composite keys from view to controller? I tried @Html.Action but it does not pass data to controller

Comment: What do you mean composite keys? And its `Html.ActionLink()`, not `Html.Action()` if you want to pass multiple route/query string values to a controller method

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke Thanks for your support. I have selected scaffolding method instead of transferring data via Ajax to controller. I have also used [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vjU6SR22Wo) to fulfil composite key issue. Thanks again